# Preventing conversion operators from compiling unless a static condition is met

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have Vector (`CVector<T, std::size_t Size>`), Matrix (`CMatrix<T, std::size_t Height, std::size_t Width>`) and Tensor (`CTensor<T, std::size_t... Sizes>`) classes, and I wish to be able to implicitly convert from a `CTensor` class to a `CVector` class if `sizeof...(Sizes) == 1` and to a `CMatrix` class if `sizeof...(Sizes) == 2`, so I have the following conversion operators (initially I didn't have the `std::enable_if` template parameter hoping I could use SFINAE to prevent it from compiling):

```
template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Sizes) == 2, int>::type = 0>
operator CMatrix<NumType, Sizes...>() const
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Sizes) == 2, "You can only convert a rank 2 tensor to a matrix");

    CMatrix<NumType, Sizes...> matResult;

    auto& arrThis = m_numArray;
    auto& arrResult = matResult.m_numArray;
    concurrency::parallel_for_each( arrResult.extent, [=, &arrThis, &arrResult]( concurrency::index<2> index ) restrict( amp ) {
        arrResult[index] = arrThis[index];
    } );

    return matResult;
}

template <typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Sizes) == 1, int>::type = 0>
operator CVector<NumType, Sizes...>() const
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Sizes) == 1, "You can only convert a rank 1 tensor to a vector");

    CVector<NumType, Sizes...> vecResult;

    auto& arrThis = m_numArray;
    auto& arrResult = vecResult.m_numArray;
    concurrency::parallel_for_each( arrResult.extent, [=, &arrThis, &arrResult]( concurrency::index<1> index ) restrict( amp ) {
        arrResult[index] = arrThis[index];
    } );

    return vecResult;
}
```

However, if I instantiate `CTensor<float, 3, 3, 3>` for instance, and try to compile, I will be presented with errors declaring that there are too many template parameters for `CMatrix` and `CVector` along with errors regarding missing type for `std::enable_if<false, int>`. Is there a way to implement these operators without having to specialize `CTensor` for rank 1 and 2?

Comment: I really don't know of any other way. Was trying to solve similar problem and ended with *base implementation* and then declaring the final class as derived from the base and specializing for other cases. BTW: Why not having CTensor only and aliasing it as CVector / CMatrix? No conversion needed, they will become the same.

Comment: @firda That's not a bad idea; I will wait and see if anyone else has a good idea (to help preventing me from having to refactor), and if not I'll definitely do this; thanks!!

Comment: Quick note, you can throw exceptions, if you really want it not to compile you limit yourself to compile time stuff, so not user input. (Tensors and vectors, I'm guessing you'll want user input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have simplified my previous solution, details below.*

SFINAE is not needed at all because you have `static_assert` in template method which is instantiated only upon usage.

My solution makes the conversion operator a template method with **dependant argument** (so that compiler does not instantiate its body, only parses signature), and adds `-1` size that pretends to be missing dimension within tensor of size 1 (not to the tensor itself, but to helper class that extracts parameter pack), to allow compiler instantiate the tensor template itself, but will not allow later on to instantiate the conversion operator within tensor of invalid dimension.

[Live demo link.](http://ideone.com/ThqTPw)

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, unsigned int index, T In, T... args>
struct GetArg
{
    static const T value = GetArg<T, index-1, args...>::value;
};

template <typename T, T In, T... args>
struct GetArg<T, 0, In, args...>
{
    static const T value = In;
};

template <typename T, T In>
struct GetArg<T, 1, In>
{
    static const T value = -1;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct CVector
{
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Height, std::size_t Width>
struct CMatrix
{
};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Sizes>
struct CTensor 
{
    template <std::size_t SZ = sizeof...(Sizes)>
    operator CVector<T, GetArg<std::size_t, 0, Sizes...>::value>() const
    {
        static_assert(SZ == 1, "You can only convert a rank 1 tensor to a vector");
        CVector<T, Sizes...> vecResult;
        return vecResult;
    }

    template <std::size_t SZ = sizeof...(Sizes)>
    operator CMatrix<T, GetArg<std::size_t, 0, Sizes...>::value, GetArg<std::size_t, 1, Sizes...>::value>() const
    {
        static_assert(SZ == 2, "You can only convert a rank 2 tensor to a matrix");
        CMatrix<T, Sizes...> matResult;
        return matResult;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CTensor<float, 3> tensor3;
    CTensor<float, 3, 3> tensor3_3;
    CTensor<float, 3, 3, 3> tensor3_3_3;
    CVector<float, 3> vec(tensor3);
    //CVector<float, 3> vec2(tensor3_3); // static_assert fails!
    CMatrix<float, 3, 3> mat(tensor3_3);
    //CMatrix<float, 3, 3> mat2(tensor3_3_3); // static_assert fails!
}
```

Comment: @Shaktal: I have just updated my solution, please see, it's even better now, as it uses static_assert instead of SFINAE

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do it with `static_assert`:

```
template <typename NumType,size_t... Sizes>
struct CTensor {
    template<size_t n,size_t m>
    operator CMatrix<NumType,n,m>() const
    {
        static_assert(
            sizeof...(Sizes)==2,
            "You can only convert a rank 2 tensor to a matrix"
        );
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<CTensor<NumType,n,m>,CTensor>::value,
            "Size mismatch"
        );

        ...    
    }

    template<size_t n>
    operator CVector<NumType,n>() const
    {
        static_assert(
            sizeof...(Sizes)==1,
            "You can only convert a rank 1 tensor to a vector"
        );
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<CTensor<NumType,n>,CTensor>::value,
            "Size mismatch"
        );

        ...    
    }
};
```

or with SFINAE:

```
template <typename NumType,size_t... Sizes>
struct CTensor {
    template<size_t n,size_t m,
      typename =
        typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_same<CTensor<NumType,n,m>,CTensor>::value, int
        >::type
    >
    operator CMatrix<NumType,n,m>() const
    {
        ...
    }

    template<size_t n,
      typename =
        typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_same<CTensor<NumType,n>,CTensor>::value, int
        >::type
    >
    operator CVector<NumType,n>() const
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

And here is another approach using function overloading:

```
template <typename NumType,size_t... Sizes>
struct CTensor {
    template<size_t n,size_t m>
    CMatrix<NumType,n,m> convert() const
    {
        ...
    }

    template<size_t n>
    CVector<NumType,n> convert() const
    {
        ...
    }

    template <typename T>
    operator T() const { return convert<Sizes...>(); }
};
```

Comment: @PiotrS.: I'm not sure that a `static_assert` was really what was desired.  It seems like that was a workaround: "initially I didn't have the std::enable_if template parameter hoping I could use SFINAE to prevent it from compiling".  However, a `static_assert` could be used easily enough.  I'll add a version with that.

Comment: @PiotrS.: The new version with `enable_if` seemed like a more normal approach to me, and it didn't involve creating more helper classes.

Comment: @VaughnCato: the current second approach looks great and so simple

Comment: @PiotrS.: Thanks.  I'll put the `static_assert` version at the top then.

Answer (score 1):

*This is actually longer description of my comment: **Why not having CTensor only and aliasing it as CVector / CMatrix? No conversion needed, they will become the same.***
...it is solving the real problem in a completely different way than the title asks for. Just for the record :)

---

1) Hiding base implementation in namespace `detail`
2) Specializing what really needs to be specialized
*(this can be done by some helper struct as well - specializing the struct providing the method)*
**3) Aliasing CVector/CMatrix as CTensor *(no need for the operator then)***

```
#include <vector>

namespace detail {

template<class T, std::size_t... Sizes>
  class base;
template<class T, std::size_t Size>
  class base<T, Size> {
    std::vector<T> data;
public:
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return data[i]; }
};
template<class T, std::size_t First, std::size_t... More>
  class base<T, First, More...> {
    std::vector<base<T, More...>> data;
public:
//  this could be done better, just an example
    base<T, More...>& operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return data[i]; }
};

}

template<class T, std::size_t... Sizes>
  class CTensor: public detail::base<T, Sizes...> {};
//we can specialize CTensor<T, Size>
//and CTensor<T, Width, Height> here
template<class T, std::size_t Size>
  using CVector = CTensor<T, Size>;
template<class T, std::size_t Width, std::size_t Height>
  using CMatrix = CTensor<T, Width, Height>;
```

Comment: With all respect, to me it does not solve the problem titled: "Preventing conversion operators from compiling unless a static condition is met", only this particular one

Comment: How should I behave if it turns out, that the real problem can possibly be solved in a completely different way, than the title states?

Answer (score 0):

Make `sizeof...(Sizes)` a dependant argument, and make the type `CMatrix`/`CVector` correct (taking the correct number of template parameter).

Using:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is> struct index_sequence {};

template <std::size_t I, typename T> struct index_element;

template <std::size_t I, std::size_t ... Is>
struct index_element<I, index_sequence<Is...> >
{
private:
    static constexpr const std::size_t a[] = {Is...};
public:
    static_assert(I < sizeof...(Is), "out of bound");
    static constexpr const std::size_t value = a[I];
};
```

then you may do:

```
template <
    std::size_t N = sizeof...(Sizes),
    typename std::enable_if<N == 1, int>::type = 0>
operator CVector<
    T,
    index_element<0, index_sequence<Sizes..., 0>
    >::value>() const
{
    // Your implementation
}

template <
    std::size_t N = sizeof...(Sizes),
    typename std::enable_if<N == 2, int>::type = 0>
operator CMatrix<
    T,
    index_element<0, index_sequence<Sizes..., 0>>::value
    index_element<1, index_sequence<Sizes..., 0, 0>>::value
    >() const
{
    // Your implementation
}
```